# Generating a random graph with bounds on degree and diameter

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

What would be a way to generate a random simple graph with diameter lesser than a given number, and in which there are given lower and upper bounds (bounds being uniform across vertices) on the degree of vertices? I know this sounds similar to the degree-diameter problem, but I am not sure if the question I ask inherits the same difficulty as that of the degree-diameter problem.

Such a graph would be one step closer (than any random graph) to representing social networks in which one knows, empirically, that the degree of separation (diameter) is at most 6 (or so) and the maximum number of connections of a node (degree) is at most 500 (or so).

Comment: You say "any" random graph. What's wrong with a random regular graph? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_regular_graph)

Comment: @SeanEberhard: I also need an upper bound on the diameter of the graph, motivated by the fact that the degree of separation (typically) is around 6. I wonder how that would be adhered to if one were to chose a random regular graph.

Comment: Even without diameter constraints, I wonder how easy it is to _uniformly_ sample a random graph with degrees within two bounds... Adding edges in an ER way until the minimal degree is reached, and taking care of not exceeding the maximal degree, seems biased, right? Should we compute the number of correct graphs with each possible number of edges, and then sample according to this?

Comment: May I add that average distance may be a more appropriate parameter than diameter? Indeed, the "small-world" estimate is not about diameter (which would require testing basically all vertex pairs). It is rather about average; and the average is much more robust (_e.g._, adding just one edge may totally change diameter, whereas it cannot change average distance much).

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: Thanks for your comments. I am not suggesting that without the diameter constraint, the problem becomes any easier. And, I am OK with constraining the average distance between pairs instead of the diameter. But I wonder how that helps. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand it correctly: the question is about _uniform_ sampling in the class of _all_ graphs having given bounds on degrees and diameter (or average distance), whatever number of vertices and edges they may have, right?

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: That's correct. In fact, after your mention, I'd be tempted to add a lower bound on the number of vertices, but that would just makes the problem harder. Plus, adding  a feasible lower bound isn't easy (at least I do not know of one). So at present, I'd not include that.

Comment: Just sample random regular graphs and repeat if the diameter is too large. By the references on wikipedia, with high probability the diameter is not too large, so you won't have to repeat very many times, unless you are asking for unrealistically low diameter, and then you're not talking about random graphs or typical social networks at all, but rather rigid graphs as in the degree diameter problem.

Comment: We know that these graphs have a number of vertices below the Moore bound. Would it make sense to sample a regular graph of this size with all vertices having the prescribed maximal degree, and then sample random sub-graphs until the other prescribed conditions are met?